# Search result in rendered child view move to child view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Two models. category and material. Category `has_many` materials. Material `belongs_to` category. 
Material has partial `_list.html.erb` which I am rendering to Category `show.html.erb`
Everthing is working find. Now, I have added search to the child view - `show.html.erb`:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <h2><%= @category.category_name %></h2>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(@category) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', categories_path %>

<p><%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>

  <%= f.label "find" %>
  <%= f.search_field :sku_or_description_cont %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

</p>
</p>
<%= render 'materials/list' %>
<p></p>
```

Searching is also working fine. But when I will click submit it will move me to `materials/index.html.erb`. I want to stay on category view and only show results of the search as a parent view.

My `categories_controler.rb` show method:

```
# GET /categories/1
# GET /categories/1.json
  def show
    @q= Material.where(:category_id => params[:id]).ransack(params[:q])
    @materials = @q.result(distinct: true).paginate :page => params[:page]
  end
```

For serching/pagination I am using Ransack (do not know if this is important or not).
What should I change to make it work as expected (search results withing categories/show view.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the url for the form, like this.

```
<p><%= search_form_for @q, url: @category do |f| %>
```

Comment: So simple. Working like a charm. Thank you.